# Why i get error diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5 in Java?

Tags: java, maven

Project was created in `Intellij IDEA` with `Maven`.
This is my settings:
[image]
[image]

Why I get error `java: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5 (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)` when try `build project`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your project object model (pom.xml) file you need to change the compiler source and target version to 1.8. Changing it any other way, via preferences or otherwise will ultimately be reset by Maven on next build due to priority. Maven by default has a compiler version of 1.5.

```java
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Comment: Best way - `change project structure` in `IDE`

Comment: @n199a Changing project structure will be overridden, that won't work.

Comment: I forgot change `level language` in `Project Structure - Modules - Language level` to `version 8`.